# Echo Array Keys: Url and Caption

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array:

```
Array
( 
      [url] => http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/img2.png 
      [caption] => title text test 
)
```

But I'm not getting the right echo on the foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($imgs as $imgurl) {   ?>          
    <input name="my_image[url]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $imgurl[url];?>"/>
    <input name="my_image[caption]" type="text" value="<?php echo $imgurl[caption];?>">

<?php
 };
?>
```

> **Warning**:  Illegal string offset 'caption' on line **42**

Comment: There is no need for `foreach`. Just use `$imgs["url"]` and `$imgs["caption"]`

Comment: @SahilGulati Is just an example I have more data in the real array, with more urls and captions

Comment: You missed `"` double quotes in `$imgurl[caption]`, change this to `$imgurl["caption"]` and also use `isset`

Comment: @SahilGulati  I put the quotation mark but the same error is still appearing

Comment: Make sure your complete array contains `url` and `caption`. Try to do it like this `<?= isset($imgurl["url"]) ? $imgurl["url"] : "";?>` and also for caption

Comment: Array
( 
      "url" => "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/img2.png ",
      "caption" => "title text test" 
);

Comment: @Gislef  how you got your initial array can you please post that code too (edit your question and add that code too)?

Answer (score 2):

Your array structure should be:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(58) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/img2.png"
    ["caption"]=>
    string(15) "title text test"
  }
}
```

if you want to use `foreach`

Comment: Thanks, how do I create an array like this? Currently the array is automatically created with `if (isset ($ _ POST ['my_image'])) {....}`

Comment: @Gislef can you show a var_dump of `$_POST['my_image']`.

Comment: var_dump of `$_POST['my_image']` return: `array(2) { ["url"]=> string(67) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/065.jpg" ["caption"]=> string(19) "test other capition" }`

Comment: You need to make ` $_POST['my_image']` a two-dimensional array

Comment: If I put this array inside another empty array it solves?

Comment: @Gislef yes, it will.

Comment: This is almost solved, but it is printing an extra variable that appears blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153316/discussion-between-just-a-simple-guy-and-gislef).

Answer (score 0):

In your case as you access array in foreach it should be two dimensional.

If it is the single array with different keys then not need to foreach. You can access it directly.